# How to identify builds triggered due to code change

Tags: teamcity

I have some build configurations added into TeamCity. I want to identify builds which are triggered via code change only. Take for example,

- I have build configurations A, B and C.
- C has snapshot dependency on A and B.
- When I make changes to C TeamCity also triggers build configurations A and B.
- Here, all three builds are triggered. I want to identify the builds which are triggered due to code change (in this case only C) and get the artifacts from those builds only.

I have several build configurations in my TeamCity and many are dependent on each other. Is there a way to achieve this? May be some file or something gets generated which will tell the build configurations triggered due to code change? I just need some pointers to identify the builds, I would implement it as it suits my project.